# How to get the last payment and the check if account is expired today or not?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to check the user is expiring today or not on base of the last payment

My payment table is like below...

```
id   user_id   create_at
32   38        2014-06-05 10:30:00
33   38        2015-06-05 01:30:00
```

My query is as below....

I am checking who has payed 1 year ago and no more payment after

```
SELECT `user`.`id`,
       date_format(max(payment.create_at), ('%Y-%m-%d')) as last_payment_at,
       `payment`.`package_id`,
       `payment`.`id` as payment_id
FROM (`user`)
LEFT JOIN `payment` ON `payment`.`user_id`=`user`.`id`
WHERE date_format(payment.create_at,('%Y-%m-%d')) = '2014-06-05'
GROUP BY `payment`.`user_id`
```

Instead of get zero row, I am getting the row payment_id `32`.

Comment: Ofcourse you're selecting the `id` !

Comment: You should be showing us the full schema needed to answer the question.

Comment: you are getting the 2014-06-05 that's why you are getting the `32`, look at this `WHERE date_format(payment.create_at,('%Y-%m-%d')) = '2014-06-05'`

Comment: @alleo-indong i can't use last_payment_at in where clause, what will be the solution..??

Comment: @parth you can try this `WHERE date_format(payment.create_at,('%Y-%m-%d')) < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)` This will get all the data that is 1 year old already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're abusing `group by` a little bit here. The general technique is to find the last payment in a subquery, and then join back to that query result. It is (almost) the only way to get the rest of the row details associated with the max/min value of another column, that you aren't also aggregating or grouping.

```
select * 
  from payments p
    inner join (
      select user_id, max(create_at) last_payment
        from payments
        group by user_id
    ) q
    on p.user_id = q.user_id
      and p.create_at = q.last_payment
    inner join user u
      on p.user_id = u.id
  where date(last_payment) = '2014-06-05'
```

[demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a2777/1)

can't be any more specific without your full table schema.